# Getting the exact location of a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Given a `UITableView`, how can I find the location of a specific `UITableViewCell`? In other words, I want to get its frame relative to my iPhone screen, not relative to the `UITableView`. So if my `UITableView` is scrolled up, the location of each `UITableViewCell` should be higher on the screen, etc.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You could also use the `rectForRowAtIndexPath` method to get the location of a `UITableView` by sending the **indexPath** for that.

```
- (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

So use as below:

```
CGRect myRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: In which function  are you accessing the `rectForRowAtIndexPath` method ?

Comment: in the didSelectRow... method

Comment: @reising1: It must not be crashed,if you still have the same issue you could show the related code .

Answer (score 64):

Apart from rectForRowAtIndexPath you need to consider the scrolling.

Try this code:

```
 // Get the cell rect and adjust it to consider scroll offset
 CGRect cellRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 cellRect = CGRectOffset(cellRect, -tableView.contentOffset.x, -tableView.contentOffset.y);
```

Comment: That yields in the screen coordinates of the cell, +1 !

Comment: +1 for taking into consideration the content offset. This will map the cell to its screen coordinates instead. nice one
thanks.

Comment: The second line can be made simpler: `cellRect = CGRectOffset(cellRect, -tableView.contentOffset.x, -tableView.contentOffset.y);`

Comment: You may also want to subtract the tableview's contentInsets if you have any `(-tableView.contentOffset.y-tableView.contentInset.top)`

Comment: `rectForRowAtIndex` will return the rect in the UITableView's coordinate system. Use the  `convertRect` method  as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687793/determine-coordinates-of-a-uitableviewcell-while-scrolling to convert it to the super view's coordinate system instead of fiddling with the offsets and insets manually.

Answer (score 23):

Try the following(sending nil as a toView parameter means you want to convert you rect to window coordinates):

```
CGRect r = [cell convertRect:cell.frame toView:nil];
```

And remember that if particular row is not currently visible then there may not be UITableViewCell for it - so before using that code you may need to check if cell is valid (not nil for example)

Comment: this is throwing an error. the program terminates. and yes, the cell is visible.

Comment: what is the error message? and how do you get your cell object?

Answer (score 17):

**Swift 3**

Relative to the `tableView`:

```
let rect = self.tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
```

Relative to the `Screen`:

If you only know the `cell`,

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
     let rect = self.tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
     let rectInScreen = self.tableView.convert(rect, to: tableView.superview)
}
```

If you know the `indexPath` then don't need call the `if` statement.

Answer (score 9):

try it 
in

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


        // get current location of selected cell

        CGRect rectInTableView = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        CGRect rectInSuperview = [tableView convertRect:rectInTableView toView:[tableView superview]];


         NSLog(@"Cell Y Is %f",rectInSuperview.origin.y);

        NSLog(@"Cell X Is %f",rectInSuperview.origin.x);
```

Answer (score 5):

Jhaliya's answer wasn't quite enough for me, I needed to do some more manipulations to get it working. My tableView was added to a viewController and its location on the right half way down the screen. So you need to take the tableView origin into account aswel as the scroll offset.

```
CGRect rowRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGPoint offsetPoint = [self.infoTableView contentOffset];

// remove the offset from the rowRect
rowRect.origin.y -= offsetPoint.y;

// Move to the actual position of the tableView
rowRect.origin.x += self.infoTableView.frame.origin.x;
rowRect.origin.y += self.infoTableView.frame.origin.y;
```

Answer (score 1):

For future viewers, I was having trouble getting a reliable frame for cells in a `UITableView`. I was trying to display a `UIAlertController` in ActionSheet style on an iPad which needs a popover presentation. In the end this approach yielded the best results:

```
// 44 is the standard height for a cell in a UITableView
// path is the index path of the relevant row
// controller is the UIAlertController
CGRect frame = CGRectZero;
frame.origin.y = 44 * path.row;
frame.origin.x = table.frame.origin.x;
frame.size = CGSizeMake(table.frame.size.width, 44);
controller.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = [tableView convertRect:frame toView:self.view];
controller.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
```

Comment: I ended up using your answer. Instead of hard coding it to 44 you should use cellForRowAtIndexPath and then use the bounds.height of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Swift-version of Tomasz and Jhaliya's answers in case anyone (else) struggles with this:

```
var cellRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
cellRect = cellRect.offsetBy(dx: -tableView.contentOffset.x, dy: -tableView.contentOffset.y)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to convert specifically to a point in the window, you could do this:

```
[yourAppDelegate.window convertPoint:[cell.contentView.center] fromView:[cell.contentView]];
```

I used the cells center coordinate, but you could use any point you want.

Vladimir is right, watch out for rows that are not visible (or that have been recycled).

-S