# Taking a screenShot of view inside a cell in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, screenshot, uigraphicscontext

I am trying to take a screen shot of view inside a cell of `UITableView` but with attached code I can able only to take a screenshot of cell bounds. The problem is that by `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f)`. I can only make screenshot of rect size and cannot control origin of rect and 
`rect = [cell bounds]`. so please suggest me some idea.

```
{
  UITableViewCell*  cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
  __block  CGRect rect = [cell bounds];
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  [cell.layer renderInContext:context];
  UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: Just change `[cell bounds]` with the frame of the view inside that cell that you need to take image of? Have you tried that?

Comment: i think instead of [cell.layer renderInContext:context]; you should be doing [cell.DesiredView.layer renderInContext:context]; you want to put what you want in the screenshot in the context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the screenShot as a normal screenShot and then crop it

```
-(UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)image rect:(CGRect)cropRect
{
   CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], cropRect);
   UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
   CGImageRelease(imageRef);
   return img;
}
```

Use like this:

```
 UIImage *img = [self cropImage:viewImage rect:CGRectMake(150,150,100,100)];
```

To get the frame of a particular tableView Cell. Use this:

```
CGRect myRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:0];//example 0,1,indexPath
```

Hope this helps. Refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687909/ios-screenshot-part-of-the-screen) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280288/getting-the-exact-location-of-a-uitableviewcell)

Comment: Someone wants his critic badge

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage *) screenshot {

     CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

     CGRect rec = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height); //set the frame 
     [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:rec afterScreenUpdates:YES];

     image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
     return image;
```

}