# convertRect to get relative position in super view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview

I have a bunch of horizontal UITableView which is put inside a UIViewController1. I wanted to find the position of the UITableViewCell that is tapped, I wanted to get the position in terms of the UIViewController1. So here's what I did in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                UIView *animatedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
 [animatedView setFrame:[animatedView convertRect:animatedView.frame toView:self.newsRackController.view]];
```

However it seems that this doesn't convert it correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4620507/442328).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to convert the CGRect of the UITableViewCell from the UITableView's view and then convert it again to your view controllers view.

But instead of all that, perhaps you could just use UITableView's method

```
- (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Get this CGRect and convert it to your UIViewController's View.

Comment: For me this solution doesn't take into account the contentOffset or contentInset.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `animatedView` does not belong to any parents, and you are using `frame` as `bounds`. You should find the frame first and init `animatedView` accordingly.

```
MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGRect animatedViewFrame = [tableView convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.newsRackController.view];
UIView *animatedView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:animatedViewFrame];
```